# How can Informatica do the job of a link collector in Datastage?

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

Is it possible to replicate the functionality of link collector in Datastage in Informatica, using its pre-built transformations?

I have 4 different streams in the same mapping. I want a union of all the streams. It may or may not relate to one another. Hence I do not have a common column. I just want to dump values from those 4 streams into a single column in informatica. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Does each input stream contain a single column **OR** multiple columns different for every stream?

Comment: It contains single column, all values from the different steams should merge into one column in the target table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Union` transformation allows you to define a number of input groups and input ports (4 groups with single port in your case) and merges the source rows together.